# how to copy the config of one port to another port on juniper

Tags: juniper-junos

how to copy the config of one port to another port on juniper ?

1) how to see all the configs that are applied to the port (ex: xe)
2) then how to copy the config of this port to another port ?

currently trying to configure a switch but trying to look at all the configurations pertaining a particular port, then trying to copy the config on that port to another port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) how to see all the configs that are applied to the port (ex: xe)

```
show configuration interface xe-0/0/0 | display inheritance
```

> 2) then how to copy the config of this port to another port ?

```
delete interface xe-0/0/1        <-- removes existing configuration from destination port
copy interface xe-0/0/0 to xe-0/0/1
```